# Days count across the months with given start date and end date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snippet of a table as below :

[image]

Can somebody help me with the query that gives me report as below:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you get from the top table to the bottom one, and also what you've tried so far?

Comment: @GregPavlik :   The bottom table is what i want to achieve/generate from above/1st table which is my actual source table.I just want to divide the days (column: days_diff) between the startdate and enddate. I am new to snowflake.. i tried using cross apply but didn't work on snowflake.

Comment: Still not clear on this. Are your start & end dates truncated to the begging of the month? If so the output doesn't seem to make sense to me. Also why are there two rows with the same member ID in the bottom but only one on top. Did it get cut off in the screenshot? Can you post data in text instead of pictures?

Comment: @GregPavlik : I uploaded the wrong picture.it is updated now. I have actual startdates and enddates now. Sorry for the confusion.Please check the startdate and enddates on 1st image again. I hope the question is understandable now.

Comment: In the example where the start date and end date is 28/05/2019 to 28/06/2019 where the count is 31, what is the logic that splits your count for the month 05 & 06  which is 28 & 3

Comment: @hkandpal  : if you see the example above .. _01 member has startdate from 2019-05-28 to enddate of 2019-06-28.

Here i am trying to calculate the days enrolled by the  ......_01 member per month.
So, the month 2019-05 has 3 days (i.e. 2019-05-28 to 2019-05-31)
and the month 2019-06 has 28 days (i.e 2019-06-01 to 2019-06-30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a calendar dimension as Mike suggested (which is a good idea) the best option may be a user defined table function (UDTF). This UDTF does not depend on the DAYS_COUNT column. It calculates the days in each month and only requires a start and end date. It will generate as many rows as are required to fill the months in between.

```
select * from a, table(DAYS_IN_MONTHS(START_DATE, END_DATE));

create or replace function DAYS_IN_MONTHS(START_DATE date, END_DATE date)
returns table(MONTHS string, DAYS float)
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {},
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        
        let year  = row.START_DATE.getFullYear();
        let month = row.START_DATE.getMonth();
        
        let endYear  = row.END_DATE.getFullYear();
        let endMonth = row.END_DATE.getMonth();
        
        let isDone = year > endYear || (year == endYear && month > endMonth);
        
        if (year == endYear && month == endMonth) {
            rowWriter.writeRow({MONTHS: `${year}-${(""+(month+1)).padStart(2, '0')}`,DAYS: row.END_DATE.getDate() - row.START_DATE.getDate()});
            isDone = true;
        }

        d = row.START_DATE

        while (!isDone) {
            if (year == endYear && month == endMonth) {
                rowWriter.writeRow({MONTHS: `${year}-${(""+(month+1)).padStart(2, '0')}`,DAYS: row.END_DATE.getDate() - (d.getDate() - 1) });
                isDone = true;
            } else {
                rowWriter.writeRow({MONTHS:  `${year}-${(""+(month+1)).padStart(2, '0')}`,DAYS: new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate() - (d.getDate() - 1) });
                month++;
                if (month == 12) {
                    month = 0;
                    year++;
                }
            }
            d = new Date(year, month, 1);
        }
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {},
}
$$;
```

Comment: Glad it worked. There's not much test data so if this doesn't work with more test data let me know and I can adjust/correct.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if you'd have a calendar dimension for something like this.  As an example, you can create one with something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE calendar AS
SELECT dateadd(day,seq4(),'2017-01-01'::date) as cal_date, 
       date_trunc(month,cal_date) as cal_month_start, 
       dateadd(day,-1,(dateadd(month,1, cal_month_start))) as cal_month_end
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 10000));
```

With this `calendar` table, you can then join to it using the start and end dates and aggregate on that date to get the results.  Using a CTE to replicate your data:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT member_id, start_date, end_date
    FROM (VALUES ('461043068_02','2018-08-07'::date,'2018-08-17'::date),
                 ('461043068_01','2019-05-28'::date,'2019-06-28'::date)
         ) y (member_id, start_date, end_date)
  )
```

Now, you can query `x` and join to `calendar` as such:

```
SELECT member_id, cal_month_start, count(*)
FROM x
JOIN calendar c
  ON c.cal_date between dateadd(day,1,x.start_date) and x.end_date
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

This gives you the results you are looking for.  Please note the need to add 1 to the `start_date`, so that you don't count the "edges" of your date ranges twice.

Also, I didn't format the `cal_month_start` in my query, but you can do that using a `TO_VARCHAR()` function, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Mike for you kind response. This worked for me too.